# Export of products in CSV files

Tags: database, catalog, products, csv, export

Does anyone know why the CSV export file does not appear, when I make the export I get the notification that it is ready, however, the file is not found, this should appear with the date on which the export was made if I am not mistaken. I have made several attempts and it has not been updated for 7 days.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if **cron** working on your server or not.
And run the command below:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

You can reads in details about this command here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/start-message-queues.html?lang=en